# Normalize time variable for recurrent LSTM Neural Network using Keras

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, time-series, recurrent-neural-network

I am using Keras to create an LSTM neural-network that can predict the concentration in the blood of a certain drug. I have a dataset with time stamps on which a drug dosage was administered and when the concentration in the blood was measured. These dosage and measurement time stamps are disjoint. Furthermore several other variables are measured at all time steps (both dosage and measurements). These variables are the input for my model along with the dosages (0 when no dosage was given at time t). The observed concentration in the blood is the response variable.

I have normalized all input features using the MinMaxScaler().

**Q1:**
Now I am wondering, do I need to normalize the time variable that corresponds with all rows as well and give it as input to the model? Or can I leave this variable out since the time steps are equally spaced?

The data looks like:

```
PatientID Time Dosage DosageRate DrugConcentration
1         0    100    12         NA
1         309  100    12         NA
1         650  100    12         NA
1         1030 100    12         NA
1         1320 NA     NA         12
1         1405 100    12         NA
1         1812 90     8          NA
1         2078 90     8          NA
1         2400 NA     NA         8
2         0    120    13.5       NA
2         800  120    13.5       NA
2         920  NA     NA         16
2         1515 120    13.5       NA
2         1832 120    13.5       NA
2         2378 120    13.5       NA
2         2600 120    13.5       NA
2         3000 120    13.5       NA
2         4400 NA     NA         2
```

As you can see, the time between two consecutive dosages and measurements differs for a patient and between patients, which makes the problem difficult.

**Q2:**
One approach I can think of is aggregating on measurements intervals and taking the average dosage and SD between two measurements. Then we only predict on time stamps of which we know the observed drug concentration. Would this work, or would we lose to much information?

**Q3**
A second approach I could think of is create new data points, so that all intervals between dosages are the same and set the dosage and dosage rate at those time points to zero. The disadvantage is then, that we can only calculate the error on the time stamps on which we know the observed drug concentration. How should we tackle this?

Comment: can you share a sample of your data. I wan't to understand if no of observations per drug per subject is constant or varying. If the time differences between observations are constant or varying. Depending on these things it can be decided to go with a time series model or a flattened data input.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: @VikashSingh Could you give me advice on a logical next step, based on the structure of the data?

Comment: Actually I don't have much experience with medical data, I was also thinking how can this be done. All the data points you have are for the same drug ??

Comment: yes. The dataset is about one drug that was administered to 250 different patients. Unfortunately the intervals between measurements and dosages is not consistent, which make the problem hard. However, I want to fit a model as good as possible to the data..

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Q1, as it is stated in this [article](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series), time column can be useful for time series forecasting. You do need to normalize this time column. What I am not sure is that if you need to tranform your time values before the normalization, like using a sin/cos tranform to take into account the periodicity of the signal. I guess that you can try that and see if the prediction improves.